# Using server-sent events with cubism.js graphs

Tags: d3.js, cubism.js

Can [cubism.js](http://square.github.com/cubism/) graphs be populated with data received from [server-sent events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)? If so, would this be easy to implement?

Thank you,

/David

Comment: I think this should be possible, you'd want to have a look at making your own custom metric: https://github.com/square/cubism/wiki/Context#wiki-metric

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, Cubism wants to poll — and seems to be designed completely *around* polling, not event-driven pushes. A custom metric is simply meant to fetch data the context decides it wants, so you'd really have to write a custom **context** designed with things like server-sent events and long-polling/_changes feed architectures.

Or!

Why not write a custom metric that fakes it? Basically, provide a `context.metric` request function that's closed around a **buffer**. As you get events, put them in the buffer. Then when Cubism's context gets around to polling your metric fetch function (you can set the `clientDelay` lower since now it won't actually increase network traffic) you can ± just shift the buffer out right away.